# Вывод string из БД mysql при помощи php и mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

По сути должно работать, но особо не работает. Вопрос: в чём проблема?
Неработающий код:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['eins'])) {
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('*', '*', '*', '*');
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM `cap` WHERE QUE='".$_GET['eins']."'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo $row['ans'];
    }
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($mysqli); 
}
?>
```

В GET передаю данные 'одинone'. В таблице: que = одинone, ans = дваtwo

Answer (score -1):

попробуй так

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM 'cap' WHERE que = '$_GET[eins]'") or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Comment: не следует писать ответов вида "а попробуй вот такое бессмысленное телодвижение". Ответ надо писать только тогда, когда уверен что понял проблему и точно знаешь как её решать